# *** Error: double free or corruption (out): 0x00007fffe3465010 ***.Warning: Corrupted shared library list: 0x7ffea4000920 != 0x7ffff7ffd9d8

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, free, double-free

```
void *insert_rear_node(void *arg)
{   
  int *argument=(int *)arg;
  int value=*argument;
  //Assume that allocation is happening fine (Just like malloc , it is a custom heap allocator)

  struct Node *head=(struct Node *) RTallocate(RTpointers, sizeof(struct Node));
  struct Node *temp;
  setf_init(temp,head);

  while(value>0)
    {
      if(temp==NULL)
        {
          RTwrite_barrier(&(temp), new_node(value,NULL));
          RTwrite_barrier(&(head),temp);
          printf("Inserted %d into the list\n",head->data);
        }
      else
        {
          RTwrite_barrier(&(temp),head);
          while(temp->next!=NULL)
            {
              RTwrite_barrier(&(temp),temp->next);
            }
          RTwrite_barrier(&(temp->next),new_node(value,NULL));
          printf("Inserted %d into the list\n",temp->next->data);
        }
      value=value-1;

    }
  free(head);

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  long heap_size = (1L << 28);
  long static_size = (1L << 26);
  printf("heap_size is %ld\n", heap_size);
  RTinit_heap(heap_size, static_size, 0);                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  pthread_t thread1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  int limit=1000;
  RTpthread_create(&thread1,NULL,insert_rear_node,(void *)&limit);
}
```

Assume that RTallocate and RTwrite_barrier are 2 custom functions which work perfectly fine.
RTallocate - allocates memory on the heap
RTwrite_barrier is equivalent to an assignemnt statement.

This program simply insert nodes into a linkedlist.
Then attempts to delete the head.

> I get this error:
>   **Error in `/home/test/RT-Test/InMul': double free or corruption (out): 0x00007fffe3465010** 
>   warning: Corrupted shared library list:
>   0x7ffea4000920 != 0x7ffff7ffd9d8
>   ======= Backtrace: ========= 
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7ffff77f97e5]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7fe0a)[0x7ffff7801e0a]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7ffff780598c]
>   /home/test/RT-Test/InMul[0x400b98]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtgc.so(rtalloc_start_thread+0x1ef)[0x7ffff7b4fa2c]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76ba)[0x7ffff756c6ba]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7ffff788882d]

I am freeing the head only once. Why am I facing this issue?
0x00007fffe3465010 is the address of the head.

Comment: Why, by the great god of C, beginner always write linked list ?

Comment: Don't use free when you didn't use malloc, use the equivalent to RTallocate.

Comment: *"Assume that RTallocate and RTwrite_barrier are 2 custom functions which work perfectly fine*"  That's a big assumption.

Comment: @Tony J - I will be shocked if that is not the answer.

Comment: my guess is that head is a local pointer, and `struct Node *temp;
  setf_init(temp,head);` (and what follows) inserts/appends to this local.

Comment: @Stargateur: Because they are the most simple data structures - if the basics are taught and understood well. Which other complex type would you recommend?

Comment: @Olaf Use a library that handle list for you. Honestly, I don't know :p. Array(or dynamic allocation) are more easy for beginner (and more faster on a lot of case).

Comment: @Stargateur: I beg to differ. This is basic stuff, a library would only *add* complexity (like here, in the magic `RTwrite_barrier()` function) But this secret function *could* use a (spin)lock, and the linked list *could* be a double linked list, but we basically cannot tell.

Comment: @Stargateur: Yes and using Pytghon would remove all UB and pointer related questions, too. Oh, there is one problem: One does not learn how to use pointers with that approach ;-). I have no idea about other's courses, but of course arrays and pointer basics should be treated before lists (I think I covered that in my former comment with "if the basics are taught and understood well" - that seems to be the actual crux.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use free() when you didn't use malloc() for head. Use the free equivalent to RTallocate.

Comment: Maybe the documentation of `RTallocate()` tell to use `free()` on the returning pointer ? Your answer assume a lot of thing. OP question can't be answered in this state.

Answer (score 1):

Some piece of code you didn't show us, quite probably *nowhere near* the code you think is the problem, has corrupted `malloc`'s internal bookkeeping data.

Run your program under [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org) and fix the *very first* invalid operation that it reports.  Repeat until valgrind has no more complaints.  Now your program should work.  If you do not understand valgrind's output, edit the *first* 20 or so lines of it into your question and we may be able to explain.

Comment: While this is good advice, it does not answer the question.  Should be a comment.

Comment: I don't agree with that assessment.  This is as much answer as it is possible to give without seeing OP's complete program.